# delete a mysql record using multiple selectors

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, echo

I am trying to delete a record in a MYSQL database when I need to select two simultaneous columns with the WHERE clause:

```
 $result3 = mysqli_query($con, " DELETE FROM Waiting WHERE ToUser='$ToEmail' AND ImageID='$ToEmailDB' ");
    if ($result3==false) {
        echo "No images waiting for " . $ToEmail . " for image " . $ToEmailDB;
    }
    else {
        echo "Image and record deleted for " . $ToEmail . " for image " . $ToFileName . ".jpg and record " .                   $GuessImageID;
    }
```

When I execute this statement `$result3 returns true` but the entry is not deleted. What do I need to change in my formatting?  The strings echo back correct data entered in the table.

Comment: Did you try display query and run it manually through some db client? What do you get in response?

Comment: In my testing I used the Android Studio debugger to inspect echo returns, and also used a simple html interface to talk to the server script for initial debugging.  I used MyPHPAdmin on the server to inspect the database content and watch for changes.  As a side note, Eclipse kept crashing on me during debugging so I switched to Android Studio.  So far Android Studio is MUCH more stable and easier to debug with.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be,

```
"DELETE from Waiting WHERE ToUser = '" . $ToEmail . "' AND ImageID = '" . $ToEmailDB . "'"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result3 = mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM Waiting WHERE ToUser='".$ToEmail."' AND ImageID='".$ToEmailDB."' ");
```

Comment: That worked.  There's seems to be more than one variation of the string syntax that works though.  I need to find a learning source on formatting these query strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your query always returns `TRUE` if its executed successfuly. Only on query failures it returns `FALSE` As per the `PHP` [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

```
 mysqli_query() Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, 
 DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object.
 For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.
```

**From Moby04's Comment**

If you want to check if something was actually deleted use [`mysqli_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) function.

Comment: True, if you want to check if something was actually deleted use mysqli_affected_rows function (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)

Answer (score 0):

The query will return true if the SQL query executes successfully, even when the DELETE didn't remove any rows in the DB.

> http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

To answer your question, you need to find the number of rows affected

```
$result3 = mysqli_query($con, " DELETE FROM Waiting WHERE ToUser='$ToEmail' AND ImageID='$ToEmailDB' ");

if (!$result3) {
    echo "A database error occurred";
}
else if (mysqli_affected_rows($con) == 0) {
    echo "No images waiting for " . $ToEmail . " for image " . $ToEmailDB;
}
else {
    echo "Image and record deleted for " . $ToEmail . " for image " . $ToFileName . ".jpg and record " . $GuessImageID;
}
```